Where do animes get ambient sounds from?
There is an ambient sound that I've heard a lot of times in many different animes. I've never paid attention to which production companies did those animes, but every time I hear that ambient sound in another anime, I wonder if there is like a huge repository of ambient sounds for anime productions somewhere or just coincidentally all animes I've heard it were made by the same production company, which I doubt. It's an outdoor ambient sound of crickets and birds singing, it's so typical and it's in a lot of animes. I believe most animes I've heard it are relatively new animes, like 15 years old or less.

Stock audio is a business :)

BTW, an anime/episode I just heard it is DEAD DEAD DEMONS DEDEDEDE DESTRUCTION, episode 1 (it has episode zero) 13 minute 46 seconds

Another anime I've heard it is Kaii to Otome to Kamikakushi episode 12
